# Usage of Data payload with FCM does not 'wake up' iOS mobile app when it is closed\terminated by the user explicitly?

Tags: c#, ios, cordova, cordova-plugin-fcm

In my mobile App, we a requirement to show the count of unread notifications in the notification area (with notification stacking) and also show the notification even when the application is closed \terminated by the user.

We decided to use **data payload** so that we can develop our custom event handler to show the unread notification count and implement our custom logic to show notification stacking.
This working perfectly fine for an Android mobile app. But in the case of the iOS mobile app, the incoming push notification is not 'waking up' the iOS mobile application when that application is **closed \terminated by the user explicitly**.

I have referred some of the solutions found online which include the settings ‘content_available =1 and\or setting priority to High but nothing is worked so far.
It would be great if anybody shares their experience\solution on this topic.

We are using firebase cloud messaging to push the notifications to the mobile app and we are using Cordova plugin on the client side.
My mobile app does not use GPS or Voice over IP (like WhatsUp which receives the special treatment from iOS) .

Does anybody have a prior working solution for this problem?